# MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to know and understand if MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online can have an ON-PRIM DB. My application (MS CRM 2013) will reside on MS Cloud however the data will reside on my on-prim instance. (Typical hybrid scenario).

Is this kind of implementation supported by MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online?

Answer (score 7):

No, CRM Online can't use your On-Prem DB.

Comment: can you share some links / articles that substantiates what you are suggesting?

Comment: I don't suggest anything. I just wrote that scenario you've asked can't be implemented.

Comment: This. And check comment from FireLeopard if your only goal is to have control over your SQL database, have an on-prem Dynamics installed on Azure. Another option is to host an on-prem on your own server using IFD. Hope this clarifies your options.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the only way would be a hosted Dynamics (on-premises) instance installed in the cloud, say in Azure on standard virtual servers, then having a VPN between the cloud server and the in-house DB server.

Not strictly speaking MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online, but would allow you front-end to be in the cloud whilst your data is all on-premises. It's also worth noting that, due to latency, this setup may experience performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible - CRM hosts its own DB. Azure will only let you host custom code, which you can use as SOA app. server on Cloud.